# Calculate the area of the surface $z = 1-x-y$, there $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I need some help with the follwing question.

Calculate the area of the surface $$z = 1-x-y$$, there $$x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1$$

So we know that $$r = (x,y,1-x-y)$$. This gives us that $$r'x = (1,0,-1)$$ and $$r'y = (0,1,-1)$$
The cross product of r'x and r'y gives us $$i-j+k$$ or (1,-1,1). The magnitude of the cross product gives us the sqrt (3).
So now we have the surface integral:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{3} dxdy $$
But when solving this I get $$2\pi\sqrt3$$
when the actual correct answer to the question is $$\pi\sqrt3$$
I think the problem might be in the boundaries I'm using, however the area is $$x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1$$, so the radiues is between 1 and 0, and becuase it a circle it should be between $$2\pi$$ and 0.

Comment: Have you tired finding the area with a line integral and Stokes's theorem? That might get you a second opinion.

Comment: In my class Stokes theorem comes up later, so right now I have to solve it without using Stokes.

Comment: Normal vector is $<1,1,1>$ not $<1,-1,1>$.

Comment: But, the answer is $2\pi\sqrt{3}$... Hmmm...

Comment: Will you improve your text? Dots and semicolons are scattered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't consider the jacobian of your  polar parametrization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution): $$(x(\rho,\theta),y(\rho,\theta))=(\rho\cos(\theta),\rho\sin\theta),$$ wich is $\rho$ so you have an extra $\frac{1}{2}=\int_0^1\rho \,\text d\rho$.